# choice label for update another one

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine, foreign-keys

i have a choice label that contain 4 promotion , chardeg from promotion Entity

```
$builder->add('Promotion', EntityType::class, array(
           'class' => 'AppBundle:Promotion',
           'choice_label' => 'promotionName',
       ))
```

in the next choice label i want to display the students for each promotion ,
in the student Entity a have a foreign key to affect each student to his promotion

when i choose for exemple the 2015 promotion , all students have this foreign key charged to the second label choice etc

Answer (score 1):

You basically ask for a dynamic `choice_label`, which is easy since Symfony 2.7: http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-7-choice-form-type-refactorization

```
'choice_label' => function(Promotion $promotion) {
    return $promotion->getName() . ': ' . implode(', ', array_map(function(User $user) {
        return $user->getName();
    }, $promotion->getUsers());
}
```

This will return a label with the promotion name, followed by it's users:

```
<label>Holiday promotion: John Doe, Jane Doe</label>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer , but i think this is not what i want , i have two choice label (ComboBox) in the same page , once i choose from the first i want to display all students have the promotion value selected , notice that each student have a foreign key that reference to the promotion id

Comment: So basically do an ajax request with the selected value to the controller, which returns a list with the names of the students. Javascript has to perform the ajax request, and you can let the controller easily return a `JsonResponse`. http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html#component-http-foundation-json-response